# Inequality of $h(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{N-1}e^{-t}\prod_{i=1}^M(1+\lambda_{i}ts)^{-1}dt.$

Tags: inequality, optimization

Suppose
\begin{align}
h(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{N-1}e^{-t}\prod_{i=1}^M(1+\lambda_{i}ts)^{-1}dt.
\end{align}

where $M$ and $N$ are positive integers and $N<M$, $\lambda_i$ are distinct positive numbers, and $s$ is also positive.

Now if I have $\nu_1$,$\nu_2$, ..., $\nu_M$ which are also distinct positive numbers such that $\sum_{i=1}^M\nu_i=M$, and $\rho_i=\nu_i\lambda_i$ for $i=1,2,...,M$, and
Suppose
\begin{align}
g(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{N-1}e^{-t}\prod_{i=1}^M(1+\rho_{i}ts)^{-1}dt.
\end{align}

If I know the values of $\lambda_{i}$, can I find some $\nu_i$'s such that for large enough $s$ we always have $h(s)>g(s)$?